# How to make a column without making a table?

Tags: two-column

[image]What is the easiest way to make a text look like this in Latex? In Word I would use the tab button or make a table, but I'm guessing there is an easier way to do this in Latex.

Comment: Looks like a description environment, but a bit customized.

Comment: @barbarabeeton But the request was "without making a table" where I interpreted "table" as "tabular".

Comment: @barbarabeeton Do you mean the tabbing environment?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- thanks.  that was a terrible goof!  `tabbing` it is.  misleading comments deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newenvironment{mydescription}
  {\begin{list}{}%
      {\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\textbf{##1}\hfill}%
       \setlength\labelwidth{5cm}%
       \setlength\leftmargin{\labelwidth+\labelsep}}}
  {\end{list}}
\begin{document}
\begin{mydescription}
\item [Supervisor] Xxxxxxxx\\ Yyyyyy\\ Zzzzz
\item [Instructors] Aaaaaaaa \\ Bbbbbbbbbbb\\ Cc 
\end{mydescription}
\end{document}
```